# Derivation of equation 6.15 of Introduction to Statistical Learning - 2nd ed

Tags: lasso

I was reading the book "Introduction to Statistical Learning - 2nd ed" and I can't understand the derivation of equation 6.15 on the page 247.

[image: Page 247 of ISLR]

This question is similar to [Introduction to Statistical Learning Eq. 6.12 and 6.13](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/567691/introduction-to-statistical-learning-eq-6-12-and-6-13) but the answers there weren't satisfactory.

My approach was to use the modulus definition to separate the equation 6.13 into two cases, take the partial derivative, and set it to zero.

$$(y_j - \beta_j)^2 + \lambda |\beta_j| = 
\begin{cases}
  y_j^2 - 2y_j\beta_j + \beta_j^2 + \lambda \beta_j, & \text{if } \beta_j\gt 0\\
  y_j^2 - 2y_j\beta_j + \beta_j^2 - \lambda \beta_j, & \text{if } \beta_j\lt 0\\
\end{cases}
$$

$$\frac{\partial ((y_j - \beta_j)^2 + \lambda |\beta_j|)}{\partial \beta_j} = 
\begin{cases}
  -2y_j + 2\beta_j + \lambda, & \text{if } \beta_j\gt 0\\
  -2y_j + 2\beta_j - \lambda, & \text{if } \beta_j\lt 0\\
\end{cases}
$$

$$
\frac{\partial ((y_j - \beta_j)^2 + \lambda |\beta_j|)}{\partial \beta_j} = 0 \iff
\begin{cases}
  \beta_j = y_j - \frac{\lambda}{2}, & \text{if } \beta_j\gt 0\\
  \beta_j = y_j + \frac{\lambda}{2}, & \text{if } \beta_j\lt 0\\
\end{cases}
$$

$$
\frac{\partial ((y_j - \beta_j)^2 + \lambda |\beta_j|)}{\partial \beta_j} = 0 \iff
\begin{cases}
  \beta_j = y_j - \frac{\lambda}{2}, & \text{if } y_j\gt \frac{\lambda}{2}\\
  \beta_j = y_j + \frac{\lambda}{2}, & \text{if } y_j\lt \frac{- \lambda}{2}\\
\end{cases}
$$

Now, it is clear to me that we haven't defined the function for $\frac{- \lambda}{2} \leq y_j \leq \frac{\lambda}{2}$, since $(| \beta_j |)'$ isn't defined when $\beta_j = 0$.

How can we proceed here?

Comment: You don't need a function to be differentiable to minimize it.  Consider the case of a single variable, plot the loss function, and consider how you would characterize its minimum.

Comment: For the general case, see here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/471339/derivation-of-soft-thresholding-operator-proximal-operator-of-l-1-norm (note that they have a $\frac{1}{2}$ in front of the quadratic term in their case, so replace their $\lambda$ with $\frac{\lambda}{2}$)

Comment: Let me also post my advice: rather than looking for where the derivative is zero, try starting at $\beta_j=y_j$ (which minimizes the quadratic term) and move from there towards the optimum (by considering the influence of the absolute value term).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, whuber. Considering p=1, I still have 3 "free variables", namely $y_1$, $\beta_1$ and $\lambda$, and some of the terms multiply $\beta_1$ (like $\lambda | \beta_1 |$ and $-2 y_1 \beta_1$), I am still having trouble to visualize it.

Comment: Thanks for the reference, John, I will check it out.
Following your second comment, starting with $\beta_j = y_j$, wouldn't it imply (intuitively) that we could minimize it by setting $\beta_j$ to a number slightly smaller than $y_j$?

Comment: @Xaphanius Yes, exactly! Just figure out exactly what "slightly" is, and that's your answer :)

Comment: And to follow whuber's advice, you should set $y_1$ and $\lambda$ to various arbitrary values and plot the loss as a function of $\beta_1$ in software. Here's an example in Mathematica that allows for easy toying around with $y_1,\lambda$: Plot[(y1 - b1)^2 + l*Abs[b1] /. {y1 -> 1, l -> 2}, {b1, -2, 2}]